# Como saber qual fornecedor mais fornece produtos, retornando o nome do fornecedor?

Tags: mysql

Primeiramente esse é o código que estou tentando somar os produtos de cada laboratório e exibir

```
select l.razaosocial,  sum(p.quantidade)   from produto p
inner join laboratorio l on p.fk_laboratorio_id = l.id_laboratorio;
```

Só que o resultado é a SOMA de todos os produtos independente de qual fornecedor cadastrado, e retornando o primeiro fornecedor cadastrado.

Eu queria algo que retornasse qual fornecedor mais fornece produtos, com a quantidade e o nome dele no caso, razão social....

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando [Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) para trazer os resultados agrupados por fornecedor e um [Order by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) para trazer ordenado.

Assim, por exemplo

```
Select l.razaosocial AS Fornecedor, Sum(p.quantidade) AS Qtd
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN laboratorio l ON p.fk_laboratorio_id = l.id_laboratorio
GROUP BY Fornecedor
ORDER BY Qtd DESC;
```